# MS Graph - LINQ query returning incorrect results

Tags: c#, linq, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

**Question**: Following is returning one incorrect value. What I may be missing and how can it be corrected? The issue seems to be purely related to use of `LINQ` and not MS Graph.

**Remark**: Although this is a simpler case with only two types of values (Azure AD and MS Account), in real scenarios there will be more than just two cases. Hence, we can't just use a simple ternary operator (e.g. `condition ? consequent : alternative`) for a simple case - instead, it has to be embedded with multiple cases. I'll have more than two cases as the following LINQ query shows.

**LINQ**:

`dgrdUsers` is the name of the DataGrid shown below.

```
Microsoft.Graph.IGraphServiceUsersCollectionPage users = await graphClient.Users.Request()
    .Select("displayName, userPrincipalName, userType")
    .GetAsync();

List<User> lstUsers = (List<User>)users.CurrentPage.ToList();

dgrdUsers.ItemsSource = (
            from User in lstUsers
            select new
            {
                DisplayName = User.DisplayName,
                UserPrincipalName = User.UserPrincipalName,
                UserType = User.UserType,
                Source =
                (
                    (User.UserType == "Member" && User.UserPrincipalName.Contains("#Ext#") == false) ? "Azure Active Directory" :
                    (User.UserType == "Member" && User.UserPrincipalName.Contains("#Ext#")) ? "Microsoft Account" :
                    (User.UserType == "Guest" && User.ExternalUserState == "Accepted") ? "External Azure Active Directory" :
                    (User.UserType == "Guest" && User.ExternalUserState == "PendingAcceptance") ? "Invited user" : "Unknown"
                )
            }
        ).ToList();
```

**Ref**: There are similar LINQ examples such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/936136/1232087) and [this](https://sankarsan.wordpress.com/2010/05/16/case-statement-equivalent-in-linq/)

**Resulted DataGrid**:

The `Source` column value in second row should be `Microsoft Account`.

[image]

Comment: It seems you use `Contains("#Ext#")` in your code, but the "User name" is `EXT` in upper case. So could you please try to change the `#Ext#` to `#EXT#` in your code ?

Comment: @HuryShen Thank you for pointing out the typo. It works now (with `EXT`). It seems `.Contains(...)` is case sensitive unless we use one of its other overload. You can change your comment to a `Response` and I'll mark that as an `Answer` so other readers can benefit, as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in comments: It was caused by incorrect letter case, use `#Ext#` in code but the "User Name" is `#EXT#` in upper case.

So just change the `#Ext#` to `#EXT#` in code.

Comment: I have a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63092052/1232087) if have time for a suggestion/comment etc. Thank you.