# Microsoft Graph API: returning only one user out of total 13 users

Tags: azure, uwp, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

In my `UWP` app, I am using [Microsoft Graph SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/sdks-overview). My `Azure` account has total 13 users that I want to display in my `UWP` app using the following query. But the query is returning only one (the logged in user). It happens even when I logged in as `Global admin`. Moreover, the `userType` of the user is shown as `Null`

```
var users = await graphClient.Users.Request()
    .Select("displayName, userPrincipalName, userType")
    .GetAsync();
```

Authorization `Scopes` in my App: `User.Read User.Read.All`

**Azure Portal showing the list of all users**:

**NOTE**: The above query in the `UWP` returns only one of these users (the logged in user)

[image]

**API Permissions of the [Registered App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-register-app-v2) in Azure**:

[image]

**UPDATE**:

To answer an inquiry from user `@Allen Wu`:

a) I've installed the following `NuGet` packages:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Ui.Controls -Version 6.0.0
Install-Package Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Ui.Controls.DataGrid -Version 6.0.0
Install-Package Microsoft.Toolkit.Graph.Controls -IncludePrerelease
```

And I'm using setting the variable `graphClient` as `ProviderManager.Instance.GlobalProvider.Graph;`

b) I have tested the app using the third to last account (Microsoft `hotmail` Account shown in image 1) and the second to last account (Microsoft `Outlook` account) both of which I have assigned a Global Administrator role. But they are not the Azure AD accounts.

Comment: Please share more code, including how you get the `authProvider` and `graphClient`. And what about signing in with a different account? Still only return the logged in user?

Comment: @AllenWu To answer your inquiry, I've added an **UPDATE** section to the post. See if that can help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should provide your code so that I can modify or point out the incorrect part.

But anyway I have found the reason.

The two accounts Microsoft `hotmail` Account and Microsoft `Outlook` account are actually MSA (Microsoft personal account).

Although they have been added as guest users into your tenant, if your authentication endpoint is `common`, then this account will be treated as a personal account instead of a guest user under this tenant. See reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols#endpoints). In your code you are using `common` by default, so the user is treated as MSA and it can only get its own information.

So you need to specify the **tenant id** in the request. I'm not sure how you generate the `graphClient`. But you can refer to the official document [Authorization code provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#authorization-code-provider) and [List users example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#example-1-standard-users-request).

**But still remember to modify `WithAuthority`.**

An example here:

```
IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(clientId)
    .WithRedirectUri(redirectUri)
    .WithAuthority("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant id}/v2.0")
    .WithClientSecret(clientSecret) // or .WithCertificate(certificate)
    .Build();

AuthorizationCodeProvider authProvider = new AuthorizationCodeProvider(confidentialClientApplication, scopes);

GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

var users = await graphClient.Users
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```

Comment: This is a `UWP` app and I'm using [ProviderManager Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.graph.providers.providermanager?view=win-comm-toolkit-dotnet-stable) to set the `graphClient = ProviderManager.Instance.GlobalProvider.Graph;`

Comment: @nam I look into the [uwp sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/uwp) and find that it is using `providers:InteractiveProviderBehavior` to let you sign in with auth code flow. But we can only modify the client id and scopes. It is using `common` as the authority in the bottom layer. If you want to modify the authority to your tenant id, I think you may need to implement the custom provider with MSAL.

Comment: @nam  A workaround is using MSAL to finish authorization in UWP. A sample here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-windows-uwp#use-microsoft-authentication-library-to-get-a-token-for-the-microsoft-graph-api. And you can specify the tenant id in the code. Please note this sample uses `Microsoft.Graph` rather than `ProviderManager.Instance.GlobalProvider.Graph`.

Comment: I resolved the issue from this line from your `Respone` above: `The two accounts Microsoft hotmail Account and Microsoft Outlook account are actually MSA (Microsoft personal account).`. You are correct. That was the issue. When I logged in with an Azure AD account that also has Global Admin role. It displayed all the users (not just he logged in user - as it was doing it with the hotmail and outlook account even though they also have Global Admin role assigned). Thank you for helping me out. I also liked your workaround suggestion in your last comment above and I should try that also.