# C# to find if a user was migrated from Windows Server AD to Microsoft Azure

Tags: c#, .net-core, uwp, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

In my personal Azure account, I migrated some users from a `Windows Server AD`, and some were created directly in `Azure AD`, and some users came from Microsoft Personal accounts. I have been able to display these users in a Windows Desktop app using [Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/overview) - similar to what we see in Azure Portal (as shown below). Moreover, as shown below, the `Source` of user list in Azure portal tells you whether a user was migrated from Windows Server AD or not. But I have not been able to find a way to programmatically find out if the user was migrated from Windows Server AD or not. **Question**: Is there an MS Graph API or some other way to programmatically find out out if user was migrated from Windows Server AD or not?

**Remark**: Although I am using UWP, but it should not matter. A suggestion can be related to any type of app as long as the language is C#.

**To get users list**:

```
// Get the Graph client from the provider
var graphClient = ProviderManager.Instance.GlobalProvider.Graph;

 var users = await graphClient.Users.Request()
    .Select("displayName, userPrincipalName, userType")
     .GetAsync();
```

**Users shown in Azure Portal** [For `Source Column` in my Windows Desktop app, I need to determine whether user was migrated from Windows Server AD or not]:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can distinguish the user from(or not from) Windows Server AD by the fields start with `onPremises`. If the user comes from Windows Server AD, the fields `onPremises...` will not be null. If not from Windows Server AD, the fields should be null. Please refer to below screenshot:

[image]

[image]

===================================**Update**==================================

We can use one of the fields which shown above(such as `OnPremisesUserPrincipalName`) to judge if the user from Windows Server AD or not.

Comment: There are 26 such fields in [user resource type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0). I thought these would be too much to use in a criteria. For my needs, just using `OnPremisesUserPrincipalName` field should be suffice. However, I'm not getting the expected results. I've posted the issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63207643/1232087) in case if you have any suggestions/comments.

Comment: The issue posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63207643/ms-graph-linq-query-string-not-null-or-empty-issue) has now been resolved. If you can modify your above response based on my needs (described in my comment above), I will mark your above response as an `Answer`, as well - so the other users can also benefit with it. Readers pay more attention to a response if it's an accepted one. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @nam I have improved my answer.